# Divergence Test Question

Tags: divergent-series

**How would I show this series diverges**

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^rr^3}{2r^3+3r^2+1}$$

It's a monotonically increasing sequence, so i know the series would diverge, but how would i prove this?

Comment: It's not actually monotonically increasing, because it's alternating. But the terms don't tend to $0$.

Comment: I meant the Modulus is monotonically increasing, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application of three useful results in basic analysis.

**Fact 1.** Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence. Then $a_n\to 0$ if and only if $|a_n|\to 0$.

**Fact 2.** Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence that does not converge to $0$. Then $\sum a_n$ diverges.

**Fact 3.** Let
\begin{align*}
p(t) &= a_m t^m+a_{m-1}t^{m-1}+\dotsb+a_1t+a_0 \\
q(t) &= b_n t^n+b_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\dotsb+b_1t+b_0
\end{align*}
where $a_m\neq0$ and $b_n\neq0$. Then
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}=
\begin{cases}
0 & m<n \\
a_m/b_n & m=n \\
\lambda \infty & m>n
\end{cases}
$$
where $\displaystyle\lambda=\frac{a_m}{|a_m|}=\operatorname{sign}(a_m)$.

Can you put these facts together to see why your series diverges?

Comment: would i consider r being odd and even and hence ending up with 2 different limits, therefore by the non-null test the sequence would be considered divergent??

Comment: @user148699 $r$ being odd makes no difference here.